# Is that possible to run Ubuntu desktop installer from the existing iso on my hard drive?

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I am runing debian 8 , i have a partition sd5 (100 GB ) ,Is that possible to install Ubuntu on sda5 from the existing iso without using cd or usb ?

Comment: Yes, there is a whole wiki page describing how to do just that - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot